# uninitialized constant GraphqlDevise::SchemaPlugin from graphql_devise

Tags: graphql, devise

I am currently working with graphql_devise. I have been attempting to mount it my schema, according to the documentation, I can do that by placing this code inside my schema like this:

```
class ProjectGesSchema < GraphQL::Schema
  use GraphqlDevise::SchemaPlugin.new(
    query: Types::QueryType,
    mutation: Types::MutationType,
    public_introspection: true,
    resource_loaders: [
      GraphqlDevise::ResourceLoader.new(User,
                                        only: %i[register])
    ]
  )
```

For some reason I get `uninitialized constant GraphqlDevise::SchemaPlugin`
Please can anyone help me out? I am stuck, thank you